# Likelihood ratio test seems to show little difference between models with AICc difference of 3

Tags: model-selection, multinomial-distribution, aic, likelihood-ratio

I'm running a multinomial logistic regression analysis of the behavioural responses of deer to camera traps using no reaction, reaction and strong reaction as dependent variables and season, camera and light as explanatory variables. I ran my models and selected those which best fit the data using MuMIn and it came back with these two models as those which best fit the data:

```
    (Intercept) season camera light family df logLik AICc delta  weight
6   +           +      +      <NA>  <NA>    6   -181  374   0.0 7.5e-01
7   +           +      +       +    <NA>    8   -180  377   2.9 1.8e-01
```

Model 6 is 4.2 times more likely than model 7 to be the best model in the data set and the p values for light (which is the only variable which differs between the 2 models) are statistically insignificant:

```
light p value 
r:  0.7473053 
sr: 0.3786294
```

However, when I run a likelihood ratio test using the following code:

```
> 1-pchisq(fm6$null.deviance-fm6$deviance, fm6$df.null-fm6$df.residual)
numeric(0)
> 1-pchisq(fm7$null.deviance-fm7$deviance, fm7$df.null-fm7$df.residual)
numeric(0)
```

it returns the following data:

```
> lrtest(fm7,fm6) 
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: reaction2 ~ light + camera + season
Model 2: reaction2 ~ camera + season
  #Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1   8 -179.96                     
2   6 -180.67 -2 1.4198     0.4917
```

I'm wondering why my second model is showing very little difference in likelihood given that the only variable that differs between the 2 models is light which is statistically insignificant? Could this signify that light is a pretend variable?

Further, when I run fm6 against the intercept only model using

```
> lrtest(fm6)
```

I get the following data:

```
> lrtest(fm6)
# weights:  6 (2 variable)
initial  value 219.722458 
final  value 197.280835 
converged
Likelihood ratio test
```

From what I have read this seems to signify that even my best model is not explaining the response rates of deer to camera traps very well, but I'm wondering if I am right in this conclusion?

Thanks in advance!